# How do I set the Project's 'Start External Program' setting programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, envdte, vs-extensibility

I have an `IWizard` which gets access to a `Project` variable. What code do I need to write to set the 'Start External Program' value in project properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a macro that will set the current configuration to launch calc.exe. It should be trivial to re-work this for your IWizard implementation:

```
Dim project As Project = DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(1)
Dim config As Configuration = project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration
config.Properties.Item("StartAction").Value = VSLangProj.prjStartAction.prjStartActionProgram
config.Properties.Item("StartProgram").Value = "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
```